# Excel function to test whether string contains ANY of $THESE CHARACTERS

Tags: excel

Given:

$Characters

Is there an excel function to test whether a Cell contains ANY of the Characters in $Characters?

Comment: I'm almost certain that you'll be needing to write a function for this. Should be really easy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an array formula method but it also involves the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to check the length of the string to be the $Characters string to be tested. OFFSET is a volatile formula that will recalculate whenever any value in the workbook changes.

[image: Any character within a string]

The array formula in C2 is,

```
=AND(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(MID($E$2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($E$2))), 1), $A2), 0)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered correctly, they may be filled or copied to another location.

I've used the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) which is case-insensitive. If you require a case sensitive search, substitute SEARCH for the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula that should do that.
When you confirm the formula, hold down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula which you can see in the formula bar.

`Characters` is either a range containing your list of characters (or substrings) to be tested, or an array constant.

```
=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(Characters,A1),FALSE))
```